# No output using join -- files are sorted, fields match

Tags: linux, bash

I want to join these two files by the long hash strings but when I execute the code it does emits no output at all. Both files are sorted by the field being used as a join key.

sort.txt

```
bondsba01:06997f04a7db92466a2baa6ebc8b872d
mccovwi01:07563a3fe3bbe7e3ba84431ad9d055af
thomafr04:07563a3fe3bbe7e3ba84431ad9d055af
willite01:07563a3fe3bbe7e3ba84431ad9d055af
bankser01:10a7cdd970fe135cf4f7bb55c0e3b59f
matheed01:10a7cdd970fe135cf4f7bb55c0e3b59f
ramirma02:15de21c670ae7c3f6f3f1f37029303c9
ortizda01:285e19f20beded7d215102b49d5c09a0
robinfr02:605ff764c617d3cd28dbbdd72be8f9a2
mantlmi01:65658fde58ab3c2b6e5132a39fae7cb9
mayswi01:68264bdb65b97eeae6788aa3348e553c
rodrial01:7f5d04d189dfb634e6a85bb9d9adf21e
palmera01:8b16ebc056e613024c057be590b542eb
schmimi01:8d34201a5b85900908db6cae92723617
jacksre01:8eefcfdf5990e441f0fb6f3fad709e21
mcgwima01:9ad6aaed513b73148b7d49f70afcfb32
griffke02:9cc138f8dc04cbf16240daa92d8d50e2
ottme01:a760880003e7ddedfef56acb3b09697f
pujolal01:a9a6653e48976138166de32772b1bf40
murraed02:b337e84de8752b27eda3a12363109e80
foxxji01:c399862d3b9d6b76c8436e924a68c45b
aaronha01:ccb0989662211f61edae2e26d58ea92f
ruthba01:d14220ee66aeec73c49038385428ec4c
sosasa01:d7a728a67d909e714c0774e22cb806f2
sheffga01:e2230b853516e7b05d79744fbd4c9c13
killeha01:e5f6ad6ce374177eef023bf5d0c018b6
thomeji01:f76a89f0cb91bc419542ce9fa43902dc
```

cracked.txt

```
06997f04a7db92466a2baa6ebc8b872d:762
07563a3fe3bbe7e3ba84431ad9d055af:521
10a7cdd970fe135cf4f7bb55c0e3b59f:512
15de21c670ae7c3f6f3f1f37029303c9:555
285e19f20beded7d215102b49d5c09a0:503
605ff764c617d3cd28dbbdd72be8f9a2:586
65658fde58ab3c2b6e5132a39fae7cb9:536
68264bdb65b97eeae6788aa3348e553c:660
7f5d04d189dfb634e6a85bb9d9adf21e:687
8b16ebc056e613024c057be590b542eb:569
8d34201a5b85900908db6cae92723617:548
8eefcfdf5990e441f0fb6f3fad709e21:563
9ad6aaed513b73148b7d49f70afcfb32:583
9cc138f8dc04cbf16240daa92d8d50e2:630
a760880003e7ddedfef56acb3b09697f:511
a9a6653e48976138166de32772b1bf40:560
b337e84de8752b27eda3a12363109e80:504
c399862d3b9d6b76c8436e924a68c45b:534
ccb0989662211f61edae2e26d58ea92f:755
d14220ee66aeec73c49038385428ec4c:714
d7a728a67d909e714c0774e22cb806f2:609
e2230b853516e7b05d79744fbd4c9c13:509
e5f6ad6ce374177eef023bf5d0c018b6:573
f76a89f0cb91bc419542ce9fa43902dc:612
```

Code

```
join -t ':' -1 2 -2 1 sort.txt cracked.txt
```

Comment: Whadayamean, "does nothing"? It writes perfectly correct output to stdout.

Comment: do you mean output to a new file? try `join -t ':' -1 2 -2 1 sort.txt cracked.txt 
> result_file.txt`

Comment: It doesnt output anything and when i direct it to a file the file is blank

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/0ece316bbee9242fadde988cfa543ee8, including both the code I used to test and its output.

Comment: Any chance your file might have DOS newlines or other trailing nonprintable characters? `15de21c670ae7c3f6f3f1f37029303c9$'\r'` is not the same as `15de21c670ae7c3f6f3f1f37029303c9`, and correspondingly, `join` will rightly see them as two different values.

Comment: (please, in the future, test that someone can repro your bug by copying-and-pasting from your SO question -- we get questions that depend on hidden/nonprintable characters that thus aren't actually included in the question content annoyingly frequently).

Comment: nope, those values are directly pasted from the file. Thanks for the github example i just have no Idea why mine inst printing anything

Comment: (...providing code in a form that can just be run, instead of "create these files with these different names first", also makes it easier for folks to repro -- note how I'm using functions with encapsulated heredocs in my gist for just that reason).

Comment: Just because they're pasted from the file doesn't mean they're byte-for-byte identical to the contents of that file. If your editor has your file flagged as `fileformat=dos` (to use vim terminology), that means it'll put CRLF endlines on it *when it's saved*, but not that it'll show or print them in the buffer, and thus not that they'll show up in the clipboard.

Comment: There's actually a pretty easy way to settle this. What do you get as output from `md5sum cracked.txt sort.txt`?

Comment: 271036b73822d0d2616132029302f63a  cracked.txt
94f0f781f7230d20fd8b89e0ac69e7b5  sort.txt

Comment: So, your cracked.txt has UNIX newlines, but your sort.txt has DOS ones.

Comment: Run `dos2unix sort.txt`.

Comment: and by the way, this is literally **the very first thing** in the "before asking about problematic code" section of the [`bash` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Comment: WOW that worked. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that both input files are using UNIX newlines.

DOS text files have two character newlines (carriage return, linefeed). UNIX text files have only a linefeed.

Thus, when reading a DOS text file on UNIX, every line appears to have an extra character on the end (a CR, aka `$'\r'`). Since these characters are *carriage returns*, they send the cursor back to the beginning of the current line when printed, rather than having a visual effect, so their presence isn't always obvious.

So, when you're reading from first field of `cracked.txt`, your hashes are literal -- but when you read from the last field of `sort.txt`, they have an invisible carriage return character on the end. Thus, they never match, thus, you get no output.